# Review - First Post - Shows 1 but nothing is showing on First Post

Tags: discussion, support

I was wondering reason behind of not showing first post items

When I click on `Review`, I see `1 First Post` and after clicking on the click I see no questions.

Initially I thought someone might reviewed it but after couple of times refreshing the browser too I see still `1 First Post` on `Review` section

### Pic-1:

[image: 1 First Post]

### Pic-2:

[image: There are no questions]

> Whether issue is because of the review locked by another user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [StackExchange FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161390/what-are-the-review-queues), we each get our own version of the review queue. So review items don't seem to be a locked specifically by another user, but eventually the items get removed ("...exact amount depends upon the queue and review action done" per [Manishearth](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161390/what-are-the-review-queues)).

I'd suspect either StackExchange or the browser caches the the First Posts overview (showing 1 post) or you've already acted on the post earlier. Maybe try an "ignore cache" refresh with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>?

Comment: I tried CTRL+F5 at that instance, but no luck.

Comment: In my queue it currently shows 0 first posts, which should be the same for you I guess. Else it looks like there is an issue in your view indeed, if it remains I suggest we flag this post for moderator attention and seek help with the SE team (you can also mail them as indicated in the email most of us have received yesterday about the leaderboard).

Comment: I currently show 0 first posts as well.

Comment: @BartKoopman: Ok, then I will send an email to the email ID which is mentioned in the yesterdays email for the moderator attention.